# Problem in injecting content.js on clicking action toolbar icon

Tags: google-chrome-extension

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#functionality) To inject content script, worked on all the three  methods to inject content script but getting an error

`Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

My manifes.json file

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Job Scraping API",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "sidePanel",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "assets/js/service-worker.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_title": "Click to open panel"
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [ "login.html", "signup.html" ],
      "matches": [ "*://*/*" ]
    }
  ],
  "side_panel": {
    "default_path": "side-panel.html"
  },
  "icons": {
   "96" : "assets/brand_96.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["assets/js/content.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

and my service-worker.js file code

```
const GOOGLE_ORIGIN = 'https://';

// Allows users to open the side panel by clicking on the action toolbar icon
chrome.sidePanel
.setPanelBehavior({ openPanelOnActionClick: true })
.catch((error) => console.error(error));

chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, async function (tabs) {
    await chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: "scrapeJobData" }, function (response){
       displayOutput(response.data);
    });
});


chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(async (tabId, info, tab) => {
    if (!tab.url) return;
    const url = new URL(tab.url);
    // Enables the side panel on all sites that start with https://
    if (url.origin.startsWith(GOOGLE_ORIGIN)) {
        await chrome.sidePanel.setOptions({
        tabId,
        path: 'side-panel.html',
        enabled: true
        });
    } else {
        // Disables the side panel on all other sites
        await chrome.sidePanel.setOptions({
        tabId,
        enabled: false
        });
    }
});
```

Installed extension with load unpacked and pinned the extension and upon action toolbar icon i was expecting the content.js file to get executed but got error on all the three [documented](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#functionality) inject method.

Error
`Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.`

When i refresed the page and then again opend my extension the content script gets injected, everytime i have to refresh the page before opening my extension to inject content scrpit